# Use :not() pseudo-class in IE7/IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

is there any way I can get the `:not()` pseudo-class to work in Internet Explorer 7/8? Is there any javascript that can do the same thing as the CSS3 `:not()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Or you can use Dean Edwards [IE7.js](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2010/03/ie7js-update/)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, as regards JavaScript, jQuery and MooTools support the `:not` pseudo-class selector.

http://mootools.net/docs/core/Utilities/Selectors#Selector:not
http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Try using this css3 selectors for ie:

http://selectivizr.com/

Comment: Unfortunately :not is 'not' applied https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ie-css3/4K4Q8pUMFTg

Comment: @silversky Selectivizr supports :not as of v0.9.7b. See changelog at https://github.com/keithclark/selectivizr/blob/master/changelog.txt