# How do you bind a click to an element where the parent doesn't have a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add a click bind to the `icon-next` class if the `td` element doesn't have the `ui-disabled` class without using if statements if possible (no pun).

```
$(".icon-next:not(.ui-disabled)").bind('click',function(){});
```

Comment: Bear in mind that the click event will not be assigned automatically to elements that lose the `ui-disabled` class later on during runtime.

Comment: What version of jquery? the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers since 1.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do it like this:

```
$("td:not(.ui-disabled) .icon-next").bind("click",function(){});
```

As [Johannes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21126391/1879895) said, it would be a better idea to use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) in order to delegate the event in case the `.ui-disabled` class is removed.

```
$("body").on("click", "td:not(.ui-disabled) .icon-next", function(){});
```

Comment: It should be noted that the `:not` selector does not work in IE8 and below. Though I'm not sure if JQuery compenstates for it. Otherwise you'll need [an alternative solution for IE8 and below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077146/use-not-pseudo-class-in-ie7-ie8).

Comment: @Johannes: That's unrelated to jQuery selectors, you're talking about CSS.

Comment: @MMM, that's good to know. I assumed they shared not just syntax but also functionality. I learned something new :)

Answer (score 2):

[Billy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21126313/573634) was spot on with his code, though I would suggest you use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead and use a delegated event so that events are properly bound/unbound.

```
$('body').on("click", "td:not(.ui-disabled) .icon-next", function(){});
```