# Select all elements that aren't wrapped in a specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I want to select `<p>` tag and set it some properties except when it's wrapped into `<span>` tag.

How can I do that?

```html
<div>
      <p></p>
</div>
<div>
     <span>
       <p></p>          // except this one - because it's warped into span tag
     <span>
</div>
<div>
     <div>
        <p></p>
     </div>
 </div>
<ul>
    <li>
        <p></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Maybe something like this:

```
p:not(span p) { 
    // CSS properties here
}
```

But the most of my website's user use old browsers like IE8 *(as you know it doesn't support CSS3)*. So how can I do that?

Comment: For older Browsers you can use JavaScript. Or don't use `:not()` and just be inclusive instead of exclusive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:not()` to exclude the elements inside a span

```js
$('p:not(span p)').each(function(){
 console.log($(this).text())

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <p>p1</p>
</div>
<div>
    <span>
       <p>p2</p>          // except this one - because it's warped into <span> tag
    <span>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <p>p3</p>
    </div>
</div>
<ul>
    <li>
        <p>p4</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

One modern CSS method would look like this:

```css
:not(span) > p { background-color: aqua; } /* select all p elements who's parent
                                              is not a span */
```

```html
<div>
    <p>YES</p>
</div>
<div>
    <span>
       <p>NO, because it's wrapped into <code>span</code> tag</p>
    </span>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <p>YES</p>
    </div>
</div>
<ul>
    <li>
        <p>YES</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Your proposed solution...

```
p:not(span p)
```

would not work for a couple of reasons. Primarily, however, the `:not` pseudo-class, in today's CSS, only accepts *simple selectors* as an argument. Neither complex or compound selectors would work. This changes in Selectors 4, which currently has very little browser support. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37305971/3597276).

Also, for `:not`-like CSS targeting to work in IE8 would require JS/jQuery. Here are some options: [Use :not() pseudo-class in IE7/IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3077146/3597276)