# JQuery: how to exclude from selection div elements that contain a span element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have selected a group of `div` elements from a table, filtered the selection to only the `div` elements that contain the class `__gwt_cell`, and I have saved them into an array, with this command

```
var myarray = $('table > tbody > tr > td > div').filter('div[__gwt_cell]')
```

Now I would like to exclude from this selection all the `div` elements that contain a `span` element, so all the snippets like this:

```
<div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-615" tabindex="0">
    <span class="gwt-CheckBox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" tabindex="-1" value="on" id="gwt-uid-708"> 
        <label for="gwt-uid-708"></label>
    </span>
</div>
```

In order to do this, I have read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38799772/7658051), reverted the syntax of the solution, and wrote this command

```
var myarray = $('table > tbody > tr > td > div').filter('div[__gwt_cell]').filter('div:not(div span)');
```

that unfortunately does not work.

How can I get the desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the [:has() selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) is what you need

```
var myarray = $('table > tbody > tr > td > div').filter('div[__gwt_cell]').not('div:has(span)');
```

the last piece of the command,
that is `.not('div:has(span)')` , is saying

"exclude `div` elements that have at least one `span` element as [child](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_children.asp)"